# Error with testFlight There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit. > An App ID with Identifier

Tags: ios, testflight, bundle-identifier

following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1CcCKQHjDpw) tutorial I try to upload an app for use with testflight, but I got this error:

> There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
>   An App ID with Identifier 'com.myname.appName' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string.

I followed this and on Xcode 10.1 doing the following.

- set "device" on generic iOS devices
- product / archive /
- choice iOS app store
- upload / let pre-Flagged choices
- automatically manage signings
- at this point I app's recap I see[image]
- I go to developers site developer.apple.com
- try to add a new app id and got this error about my bundle

> There were errors in the data supplied. Please correct and re-submit.
>   An App ID with Identifier 'net.myname.appNamet' is not available.
>   Please enter a different string.

maybe there is a problem with my step's order?

TO BE CLEAR
- I have a valid iOS developer profile (payed and valid)
- this is the first time this app with this name was submitted
- I have only one profile
- in my developer.apple.com app id's section there are no other ids with same bundle name
- how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`com.myname.appName` needs to match what you registered with Apple.

Mine is set to `com.paulsolt.AppNameHere` ... so for Brew Coffee I use `com.paulsolt.BrewCoffee` where the last part is changed per app.

That first part needs to match what was registered. `net.myname` or `com.myname` doesn't sound like it's the right value.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you registered the App ID with a free developer account and now you are using a paid developer account? I had the same problem and came across this post in the Apple forums. Looks like any App IDs provisioned with free accounts cannot be converted to paid accounts and you'll have to create a new one and switch over your app to use it. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107232